# What is the word to describe adding commas or other characters to a number to make it more readable?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was on a technical site about to ask how to change the number 10000000 to 10,000,000 using the relevant technology. However when I started to write the question I did not how to actually write the question because I could not think of the right word to use.

Can you please let me know to word, is it just to add commas?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping) uses various dull, longwinded expressions for the comma: "thousands separators", "digit group separators", or the more general "delimiters". Do you want a verb, a noun, or what? Can you provide your question with a blank in the place?

Comment: Here is the actual question I want to improve https://superuser.com/questions/1822548/how-to-add-commas-to-a-number-using-an-excel-formula. 

Not sure If I want a verb or a noun, thinking the question might do but improved usage would be helpful.

Comment: You use the term "comma Seperators" [sic] in that superuser question. Using "comma separators" is widely understood.

Comment: You want to format your number output with commas.

Comment: Reminder: questions about naming things in computer programs are off-topic here.

Comment: @alphabet this is not about naming things in a computer program, its about wording for something im trying to do while utilising a computer program. I could have asked the question without mentioning the reason for it as adding seperators to larget numbers would have been done prior to computer programs existing.  BTW weather vane answered my question.

Comment: I've been programming for over 40 years, and I've never heard anyone use a succinct word for this process. It's just called "formatting numbers" or "number formatting". Adding commas is understood as one aspect of this.

Comment: [Wikipedia page for *lakh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) calls it *digit grouping*.   Like the Wikipedia page in first reply.

Comment: related, with good examples - https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26632/number-formatting-use-of-digit-separators-in-manuscripts

Comment: The usual terminology is _display numbers in comma format_.